# Connected frontier implies connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open with connected and $C^1$ boundary. Does it follow that $U$ is connected?

Comment: what do you mean with $C^1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that the boundary is $C^1$ in the sense that $\partial U$ is a differentiable manifold.

In this case, the answer is no: consider $$U = \{(x_1 \ldots x_n): x_n \neq 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$$ This has smooth, connected boundary $$\partial U = \{(x_1 \ldots x_n): x_n = 0\}.$$ But it is not connected.